# What is the best approach for the "lock file" pattern in spring applications?

Tags: spring

I am looking for a way to implement the "lock file" pattern in a spring application. What I want to prevent is multiple copies of the same spring application from starting using the same resources ( e.g. database ) at the same time. I know that in unix systems it is common for an app to create a file called ".lock" as it is starting up and refuse to start if that file already exists. This prevents multiple instances from running on the same server. I have some ideas about applying this pattern to the problem of multiple spring applications running against the same database but I want to know if there is anything that has been developed specifically for this problem that is more general or built in to the framework.

Comment: Why should multiple instances of that application running against the same database be a problem? Shouldn't your application be releasing database connections when they are no longer needed?

Comment: It isn't a matter of releasing database connections. The issue is that the same work might be performed in both application contexts leading to inconsistent or corrupted data. I'm sure things could be designed so that multiple app contexts are not a problem but that is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for such a solution also, and could not find any.
Implementation should be easy,

- check/create the lock file on startup
- remove it with a JVM shutdown hook (so it gets removed even if the app crashes)

If the JVM crashes (e.g. out of memory) the file will not be removed, I think there is no way to avoid that.